# installing node.js on dedicated server

Tags: linux, node.js

ok so I got a dedicated linux server and I'm trying to install node.js

i ran

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.11.tar.gz
tar zxf node-v0.4.11.tar.gz
cd node-v0.4.11
```

all is well

then i ran

```
 ./configure
```

and i got

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : not found 
Checking for program icpc                : not found 
Checking for program c++                 : not found 
wscript:232: error: could not configure a cxx compiler!
```

so i google that error if found a page that says run this

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core
```

but then i get

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

please help me I don't know what to do now

Comment: Don't install 4.11, install 6.7 or whatever is the latest version

Comment: there is a reason why i want 4.11

Comment: Is it a stupid one? I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: haha yeah probablly some other thing I want to install doesn't work with newer versions os node.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running some debian based distro, that code should work. Since you are running CentOS, you can follow [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos) link. Different linux distros use different package managers. It looks like that debian is the most popular (ubuntu, mint, debian...) so many online tutorials you find use apt to get everything installed. Your choice is different and you should use rpm/yum. Since you are missing gcc compiler, you should try executing this command (you should probably add some more packages, not sure):

```
yum install sudo gcc-c++
```

EDIT: Updated link to serverfault.com

Comment: -bash-3.2$ su
-bash: su: command not found
-bash-3.2$ apt-get install sudo
-bash: apt-get: command not found

Comment: can you try typing: "whereis sudo". It might happen that it is not in your path.

Comment: when I do that it return "sudo:"

Comment: what version of linux are you running (I mean, what distribution)?

Comment: That explains why you don't have apt-get...apt is not package manager for CentOS, but debian based distros (like ubuntu)...for installing nodejs on cent os, you can take a look at this link: http://www.chrisabernethy.com/installing-node-js-on-centos-redhat/ I've updated my answer to make more sense for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error output tells you exactly what's missing: `sudo`. Quick Googl'ing should reveal what this tools meaning is: It lets you execute commands with root privileges, provided you have access to a user account that's privileged enough to use this functionality.

So you need root privileges to install packages. This is not surprising. If `sudo` is not installed, you most probably either

- are logged in as `root`, in which you can use `apt-get` without the `sudo` in front
- are *not* logged in as `root` and thus don't have the necessary permissions to install packages. In that case, you are unlucky and you need to talk to the administrator.

**UPDATE:** From your comment to the other answer I take it that you are running with user privileges and do not have `su` in your PATH. Do you know the root password? If yes, you can try if `/bin/su` works. If no, you don't have enough privileges.